# Why the output is same in all three cases?

Tags: c, output

Can somebody please explain why the output is same in all three snippets below.
and what exactly does the 0th element of array represents.

```
int main(void) {
    char arr[10];
    scanf("%s",&arr[0]);
    printf("%s",arr);
    return 0;
}


int main(void) {
    char arr[10];
    scanf("%s",&arr[0]);
    printf("%s",&arr);
    return 0;
}


int main(void) {
    char arr[10];
    scanf("%s",&arr[0]);
    printf("%s",*&arr);
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: What?  The 0th element is the first one.....

Comment: 'printf("%s",*&arr);' - where did that rubbish come from?

Comment: I mean in this context. here we are passing address of the first element and complete string gets stored in the arr buffer.

Answer (score 2):

`arr[0]` represents the first element of array `arr`. `&arr[0]` is the address of first element of array. In all of the three snippet, `scanf` is reading a string from standard input and will store in array `arr`.

In first snippet

```
printf("%s",arr);
```

will print the stored string in array `arr`. `%s` expects an argument of `char *` type and `&arr[0]` is of that type and so is `arr` after it will decay to pointer to its first element.

In second snippet, `&arr` is the address of array `arr` and is of type `char (*)[10]`. Using wrong specifier will invoke undefined behavior.

In third snippet, applying `*` on `&arr` will dereference back it to address of the first element of array `arr` which is of type `char *` as said above.

Snippet first and third are correct and will give same output for the same input under the condition that input string should not be greater than `10` characters including `'\0'`. Third code will invoke undefined behavior and nothing can be said in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`&` ("address of") and `*` ("dereference pointer") cancel each other out, so `*&foo` is the same as `foo`.

Your second snippet is wrong. It passes `&arr` (a pointer to an array of 10 chars, `char (*)[10]`) to `printf` `%s`, which expects a pointer to char (`char *`). It just so happens that on your platform those two types have the same size, use the same representation, and are passed the same way to `printf`. That's why the output looks correct.

As for the difference: `arr` is a an array of chars. Evaluating an array (i.e. using it anywhere other than the operand of `&` or `sizeof`) yields a pointer to its first element.

`&arr` yields a pointer to the whole array. An array has no runtime structure (that is, at runtime an array *is* its elements), so the address of the array is also the address of its first element. It's just that the first element is smaller than the whole array and the two addresses have different types.